# How to increase the timeout of an Asp.net application MVC 4.5 framework

Tags: c#, asp.net, request, asp.net-4.5

I have an asp.net mvc 4.5 app that makes requests to a WCF service, the problem is that when the service takes more than 30 seconds the mvc cuts the connection to the service

I have already added the executionTimeout="300" and it still does not work.

A detail is that the local request works normally, but when deployed is when the error appears.

I also followed the steps of:

"Internet Information Services dialog box, expand local computer > Sites and right click Default Website and select Manage Website > Advance Settings. Expand Connection Limits, change the Time-out value"

"On the bottom panel, open Configuration Editor. In the top of Editor choose system.web/httpRuntime. Find option "executionTimeout" and set new value"

And I still can't increase the 30 seconds timeout.

Web.config:

```
<system.web>
    <httpRuntime targetFramework="4.5.1" executionTimeout="300"/>       
</system.web>
```

Comment: Where did you add `executionTimeout="300`? `I also followed the steps of:` did you do this in IIS of MVC application?

Comment: executionTimeout="300" is inside the system.web in web.conf

And yes, I did that in the Internet Information Services (IIS) administrator

Comment: What is the exact error you get?

Comment: If you are changing the IIS of MVC application, it will not change anything for the application when the external service communication dropped after some time. You need to set the time out at the WCF client level when you are calling from the MVC application. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wcf/feature-details/configuring-timeout-values-on-a-binding

Comment: Do I change the WCF service in the web.config or in the ISS?

Comment: I added the change in the ISS, and in the webconf and I still have the same problem.

    <bindings>
      <basicHttpBinding>
        <binding maxReceivedMessageSize="2147483647" sendTimeout="01:00:01">
        </binding>
        <binding name="IncreasedTimeout" sendTimeout="00:25:00">
        </binding>
      </basicHttpBinding>
      <wsHttpBinding>
        <binding sendTimeout="00:5:00" receiveTimeout="00:5:00">
        </binding>
      </wsHttpBinding>
    </bindings>